# Live countdown clock

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, clock

Basically, I am generating a computer based test and obviously I want to be presenting the timeleft in the exam for the examinee and when the countdown reaches zero submit the test.

I have the duration stored as time() in my MySQL database with other details of the test etc.

My question is regarding the best method for my live countdown timer. I am struggling to work out how I would do it so that if the student clicked to refresh the page the clock wouldnt reset.

any information would help.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I assume you store the test details in the database (so you can mark which questions are answered etc).
If you created a table which stores the testID and the startTime, you can have it so every time the page loads, it checks when the test was started, and starts the timer based on that value

**Table**

```
id | studentId | testId | startTime
------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1      | 1303214136
```

**PHP**

```
    //Time left in seconds
    $timeLeft = time() - $startTime;
```

And then pass that $timeLeft variable to Javascript to start the timer

Comment: PHP is strongly static. Not very useful. I'd look for a Javascript solution instead.

Comment: The Javascript part is needed to show the time left, but the actual code to work out how much is left on the test needs to be on the server, so there's an accurate record of what's left. See @AlexAtNet answer below. A pure Javascript implementation wouldn't work and would be foolish

Answer (score 2):

I'd make an AJAX call and get the timestamp of the date of the exam and then run a Javascript based countdown which take the actual time and subtract the exam time in order to get the time needed.

PHP based script will only work once since the PHP script is run once and then the page, once loaded, it static.

References:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [AJAX reference on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)
- [Countdown sample](http://scripts.franciscocharrua.com/countdown-clock.php)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can define `TimeOuts` and `Intervals`.

Basically, a TimeOut is a countdown before doing an action:

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
```

And an interval is a repeated action:

```
setInterval ( expression, interval );
```

So, in your case, you can set an Interval every minutes to check, with an ajax call, the time left.

More information in this good article: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: There's no need of keep AJAX calling the server. Just once could be enough to retrieve the information which is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the time on the server and do not rely on the client code - it should only display the time but not really control the test duration.

For example, you can store requesting time in the session and then calculate difference between the current time and the saved time.

Answer (score 0):

created a stopwatch/countdown a few days ago, find working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/V2S9d/

```
/*

JQUERY: STOPWATCH & COUNTDOWN

This is a basic stopwatch & countdown plugin to run with jquery. Start timer, pause it, stop it or reset it. Same behaviour with the countdown besides you need to input the countdown value in seconds first. At the end of the countdown a callback function is invoked.

Any questions, suggestions? marc.fuehnen(at)gmail.com

*/

$(document).ready(function() {

    (function($){

        $.extend({

            APP : {                

                formatTimer : function(a) {
                    if (a < 10) {
                        a = '0' + a;
                    }                              
                    return a;
                },    

                startTimer : function(dir) {

                    var a;

                    // save type
                    $.APP.dir = dir;

                    // get current date
                    $.APP.d1 = new Date();

                    switch($.APP.state) {

                        case 'pause' :

                            // resume timer
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations) and
                            // substract time difference between pause and now
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime() - $.APP.td;                            

                        break;

                        default :

                            // get current timestamp (for calculations)
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime(); 

                            // if countdown add ms based on seconds in textfield
                            if ($.APP.dir === 'cd') {
                                $.APP.t1 += parseInt($('#cd_seconds').val())*1000;
                            }    

                        break;

                    }                                   

                    // reset state
                    $.APP.state = 'alive';   
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Running');

                    // start loop
                    $.APP.loopTimer();

                },

                pauseTimer : function() {

                    // save timestamp of pause
                    $.APP.dp = new Date();
                    $.APP.tp = $.APP.dp.getTime();

                    // save elapsed time (until pause)
                    $.APP.td = $.APP.tp - $.APP.t1;

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Resume');

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'pause';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Paused');

                },

                stopTimer : function() {

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');                    

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'stop';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Stopped');

                },

                resetTimer : function() {

                    // reset display
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms,#' + $.APP.dir + '_s,#' + $.APP.dir + '_m,#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html('00');                 

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Start');                    

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'reset';  
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Reset & Idle again');

                },

                endTimer : function(callback) {

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'end';

                    // invoke callback
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback();
                    }    

                },    

                loopTimer : function() {

                    var td;
                    var d2,t2;

                    var ms = 0;
                    var s  = 0;
                    var m  = 0;
                    var h  = 0;

                    if ($.APP.state === 'alive') {

                        // get current date and convert it into 
                        // timestamp for calculations
                        d2 = new Date();
                        t2 = d2.getTime();   

                        // calculate time difference between
                        // initial and current timestamp
                        if ($.APP.dir === 'sw') {
                            td = t2 - $.APP.t1;
                        // reversed if countdown
                        } else {
                            td = $.APP.t1 - t2;
                            if (td <= 0) {
                                // if time difference is 0 end countdown
                                $.APP.endTimer(function(){
                                    $.APP.resetTimer();
                                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Ended & Reset');
                                });
                            }    
                        }    

                        // calculate milliseconds
                        ms = td%1000;
                        if (ms < 1) {
                            ms = 0;
                        } else {    
                            // calculate seconds
                            s = (td-ms)/1000;
                            if (s < 1) {
                                s = 0;
                            } else {
                                // calculate minutes   
                                var m = (s-(s%60))/60;
                                if (m < 1) {
                                    m = 0;
                                } else {
                                    // calculate hours
                                    var h = (m-(m%60))/60;
                                    if (h < 1) {
                                        h = 0;
                                    }                             
                                }    
                            }
                        }

                        // substract elapsed minutes & hours
                        ms = Math.round(ms/100);
                        s  = s-(m*60);
                        m  = m-(h*60);                                

                        // update display
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms').html($.APP.formatTimer(ms));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_s').html($.APP.formatTimer(s));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_m').html($.APP.formatTimer(m));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html($.APP.formatTimer(h));

                        // loop
                        $.APP.t = setTimeout($.APP.loopTimer,1);

                    } else {

                        // kill loop
                        clearTimeout($.APP.t);
                        return true;

                    }  

                }

            }    

        });

        $('#sw_start').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('sw');
        });    

        $('#cd_start').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('cd');
        });           

        $('#sw_stop,#cd_stop').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.stopTimer();
        });

        $('#sw_reset,#cd_reset').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.resetTimer();
        });  

        $('#sw_pause,#cd_pause').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.pauseTimer();
        });                

    })(jQuery);
```

});